# Understanding column counting python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering why when counting the number of columns in python I would use the code:

```
ROWS = len(table[0])
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does the 0 index signify?

Comment: 0 index signifies the first row of the table/dataframe. Therefore, `table[0]` is the series of all column values of the first row whose `len()` will give the number of column present in the table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 0):

The 0 index means you're looking at the first item of the list `table`. If table is a 3D list as shown below, then you can clearly see in this representation that the number of columns is equal to the length of the first list ([1,2,3]), which is 3 columns.

```
[
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`table[0]` returns you first row, and `len` returns you it's length. Since inside a table all rows have same number of elements, it doesn't matter which row to count - hence, counting first row (`[0]`) does the job!